# Raster overlay from a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, overlay, raster, r-raster

I have a matrix of 100 raster layers and I'd like to create one new layer that is the average. I understand if there were two layers I could simply use the overlay function or perhaps just use `c <- mean (a, b)`. However, I'm not sure how to proceed with the matrix.

Here is sample of the matrix:

```
[[1]]
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 175, 179, 31325  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 179, 0, 175  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : 0, 100  (min, max)
```

I have tried

```
a.avg <- mean (a.total[,])
```

and I receive the error `argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`

Comment: Do you have a `matrix` of raster layers? or a list? Or even better a stack?

Comment: I created a stack using your suggestion below before averaging, it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a `list` of `rasterLayer`s ( or perhaps a `stack` ). If you already have a `stack`, skip step one, but I assume you have a `list` not a `matrix` which I have called `mylistofrasters`...

```
#1 - Get all rasters in the list into a stack
mystack <- do.call( stack , mylistofrasters )

#2 - Take mean of each pixel in the stack returning a single raster that is the average
mean.stack <- calc( mystack , mean , na.rm = TRUE )
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is similar to the @SimonO101's answer using a simpler code.

First, let's build a list of `RasterLayer` (you can skip this step if you already have the list):

```
library(raster)

r <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
r <- init(r, runif)
lr <- lapply(1:8, function(i)r)
```

The `raster` package defines an `stack` method for lists, so you can use it directly without `do.call`:

```
s <- stack(lr)
```

Besides, there is a `mean` method for `Raster*` objects. Therefore, you don't really need `calc`:

```
mean(s, na.rm=TRUE)
```